# given point (2,6) and a line passes through point (3,0)

Tags: analytic-geometry

The question is: does the distance between the point $(2,6)$ to the that line could be $5$?

is there a solution to the problem without computing?

i would glad to know.

thanks.

Comment: The problem is wrongly posed as there are infinite lines through $(3,0)\,$ (one of them, btw, through $(2,6)\,$ , so without knowing what line exactly one cannot address the question.

Comment: what do you mean by "without computing"?

Comment: @mau - without algebraic solution, just by explaining in words.

Comment: my answer should then suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the line $y=0$ has distance 6 from the point $(2,6)$ and there is a line with distance 0 (the one through the two points) and the distance is a continuous function, yes: there are (two) lines with distance 5. If you want to know **which** lines, that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a circle with center $(2,6)$ and radius $5$

We need to show the existence of a tangent passing through $(3,0)$

As the distance between the points $(3,0),(2,6)$ is $\sqrt{(3-2)^2+(0-6)^2}>5,$ the point   $(3,0)$ is outside the circle, we know there are two tangents

Comment: thanks but i asked without algebraic (computing) just by words.

Comment: @bori12, please find modified logic

Comment: thanks. btw, is there a problem with my question as DonAntonio mentioned? i asked if it could be and not the line itself

Comment: another question how the redius is 5 and the length of the Perpendicular is also 5?

Comment: @bori12, the perpendicular distance of a tangent from the centre of the circle = radius of the circle

Comment: ok i understand now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the difference in $y$-coordinates is more than 5, so the distance is also more than 5 (I hope that's not too much computing!).

If the points would be $(3,0)$ and $(7,4)$, this simple argument doesn't work anymore and you need to start using Pythagoras.